# OpenCV's IplImage* as function parametr error

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage

I am using OpenCV library and I want to clone picture in separate function, but I cannot send address to the function

`IplImage* image = cvLoadImage( path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE ); // loading is ok

showFoundPoints(image); // -> here it shows errors

...`

//my function
int showFoundPoints(IplImage*image)
{...}

And I got this build error:
error: conversion from `IplImage*' to non-scalar type`std::string' requested

I don't get why is there conversion. It looks very simple, but I really don't know what to do with this.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the definition of `showFoundPoints` consistent in the header and the source? It would seem you have it declared differently; one taking a `std::string` and the other not.

Comment: ou god. you are right. thanks for your tip. I have predeclaration of this function more up and I completely forgot about it.